# Shutting down all lamps with minimum number of switch presses

Tags: python, mathematics

I found an [optimization problem](https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/tehtava.php?tunnus=muslam) written in Finnish but I will translate it into English. The following is an example case.

> I have \$n=120\$ lamps in a circle, and enumerated by \$L_1,…,L_{120}\$. Some of
>   them are switched on and some of them are switched off. I also have
>   been given a positive integer \$m=7\$. One every turn I choose one lamp \$L_i\$
>   and then the lamps \$L_{i−m},…,L_{i+m}\$ will change their state. I mean if lamp
>   \$L_j\$ was turned off then now it is turned on and vice versa. Indexes are
>   are modulo \$n\$ so the lamps \$L_{118},L_{119},L_1,L_2\$ are consecutive.
>
> What is the minimum number of turns to shut off all lamps and which
>   switches one must press, if the initial states of the lamps are (from
>   \$L_1\$ to \$L_{120}\$)
>
> ```
> 1010110110000100000101011001011111010111
> 1010011101001100000010001010011010110000
> 0000100110010100010010110111000000010110
> ```
>
> The list of cases is as follows:
>
> ```
> B       6               1               101101
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> C       10              2               1011010110
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> D       20              1               11111011101010111111
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> E       30              7               011100001010011011100001010011
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> F       39              6               110100111111101000011000100110111100010
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> G       53              9               0101100101111100100011100111101001001010
>                                         0010000010110
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> H       120             7               1010110110000100000101011001011111010111
>                                         1010011101001100000010001010011010110000
>                                         0000100110010100010010110111000000010110
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> I       220             27              1110111111101000100110011001100110100000
>                                         0010100011000111101100111111000001010000
>                                         1010110110011100100010011011010111100011
>                                         0101101000010000100110111101001001011010
>                                         1101001001110110001100011010111101001100
>                                         11010111110101010100
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> J       500             87              1010001101101001110001101001000101010100
>                                         0001111111001101011000000011001111111011
>                                         1001110011010111111011010100010011011001
>                                         1001101110011011100001000111110101011111
>                                         1100111100001100110011101110101100001111
>                                         1100010010011010001111000000101110101101
>                                         1010100001100011111000111001000101101000
>                                         1011111111101111000000011111010001000000
>                                         1110011110111101010010011000000100010100
>                                         0011101011010011010110011110111000010010
>                                         0111100100011010010110001000011100101001
>                                         1110111010001001011001111011111011010110
>                                         10101101111011101110
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> K       1002            83              0010100100100101000000110101111111101011
>                                         1101000101111110001110000110110110010101
>                                         1110110011011101100110111001110110010011
>                                         1101111010110011110101100001101010100011
>                                         1110001100011111110100011110100111111100
>                                         0011001011100110101100001101000001110010
>                                         0110100000100100100000011010000010111100
>                                         1110001110011110101001100111101101010000
>                                         0101010000011010011110101001001001000000
>                                         0011000100011011011001111010001101111000
>                                         0100001011010011001010111001111100110001
>                                         0011111110101101001100111101110000000000
>                                         1101100100000011000010010100010101001000
>                                         1100001000101001100110010100001000001101
>                                         1101000100001010011000101001101000100010
>                                         0011010001011101010100011101001101101100
>                                         0111110100110011001111000000001001001001
>                                         1001111001011111000010110000110010101000
>                                         1011001100111101000101000110000111010100
>                                         0010011011010111001101011001111000001011
>                                         1110101010101101111011111110100001100110
>                                         1000101100110011010000110000011011110011
>                                         0010000010000000111101101000001111101111
>                                         0100111110010101100011101001111101010000
>                                         1111100010011001110111111000101000000101
>                                         01
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> L       2107            108             0111110100011000011111101110010101100011
>                                         1001111011101001001110111110001100011001
>                                         1001010100101011101101001000010111111111
>                                         1001101010111011110100100101000101100011
>                                         1110100010010010101110100000111100101000
>                                         0111101011111100010010110000100110100100
>                                         0100110101110010110011110010101101100111
>                                         1110010011000110110111010110010100101110
>                                         0111111101110000111001111100100010010001
>                                         1010110011000101100111111001011110101110
>                                         0111010110111110110101000101100100011000
>                                         1011000011011110001111100110100010100101
>                                         1101111100110011001110010010001010101111
>                                         1000001001000110011110010011011101110100
>                                         1011111100110010011000010110010110101010
>                                         0110101000011011110001010000010001000110
>                                         1001110101001001110110111111010011010111
>                                         1111011001000110111001000011101101110001
>                                         0000011111101000010101011111011011000011
>                                         1111000000011100010011011001011000110101
>                                         1101011111100001100010110010110011000000
>                                         0001001111100101110100100011011010011100
>                                         0000001111010101000111011000110110100001
>                                         1010110011100110111010111110110000010000
>                                         1000101001111001000110000101010000010111
>                                         1011100001000110001100010000001011101110
>                                         1001111110100010010000011000100101010101
>                                         1001001001110110101000001001001100001011
>                                         0011011100011111100111001110101101110001
>                                         0111010000010011110110011011000011101001
>                                         1111011010010000101111000010000001100110
>                                         1001011101001000010101001001011111111011
>                                         1000111000100001101100101110100011111100
>                                         1011001111101111110110101111101111011111
>                                         1001111100110101110101111110010010101101
>                                         1111111111000100100111100011101110110100
>                                         0100011011001010110100101101000000110010
>                                         0010010001001110110100011111100011111101
>                                         0100110111101101010101010100110110011011
>                                         0001111111000100000111011010101011000010
>                                         0011011110110110110100011001101111001000
>                                         1000000011110011100111100000001010010011
>                                         1000011101111100000101010101010010100101
>                                         1010001011010100011011001110110010100000
>                                         1000111101111000010111111101010110110111
>                                         0110001111100011001110000100100101001111
>                                         0000111111100010011001010000010110111000
>                                         1000110110001000001100110000001011000010
>                                         1000101101110000101100100010101111100011
>                                         1000010010111101000010000110011010000001
>                                         0010001100001000001100110111110100100111
>                                         1001100110001000100101011111001011001111
>                                         110001011111001101010101001
> ================================================================================
> ```

I was wondering how to solve the case I. I tried to solve it by Sage but my algorithm seems to be too slow. How can I make the program such that it finds the optimal solution and stops the computing as it find it?

Current code:

```
room = []
input = []
m = []
F = GF(2)
room.append('B')
input.append('101101')
m.append(1)
room.append('C')
input.append('1011010110')
m.append(2)
room.append('D')
input.append('11111011101010111111')
m.append(1)
room.append('E')
input.append('011100001010011011100001010011')
m.append(7)
room.append('F')
input.append('110100111111101000011000100110111100010')
m.append(6)
room.append('G')
input.append('01011001011111001000111001111010010010100010000010110')
m.append(9)
room.append('H')
input.append(''.join([ s for s in """1010110110000100000101011001011111010111
                                        1010011101001100000010001010011010110000
                                        0000100110010100010010110111000000010110""".split('\n') if s])
m.append(7)
for case in range(len(room)):
    L_init = vector(F,input[case])
    d = len(L_init)
    print(d)
    M = matrix(F,d,d)
    print(d)
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(-m[case],m[case]+1 ):
            M[i,(i+j) % d] = 1
    I = M.solve_right(L_init)
    K = M.right_kernel()
    best = None
    for k in K:
        A = (I+k).nonzero_positions()
        B = []
        if len((I+k).nonzero_positions()) < best or best == None:
            S = room[case] + ' '
            best = len((I+k).nonzero_positions())
            for i in range(len(A)):
                S +=str(int(A[i])+1) + ' '
    print( str(S))
```

This outputs:   File "lampsB.sage.py", line 32
    m.append(_sage_const_7 )
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I also found discussion in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569003/how-to-find-an-algorithm-to-shut-down-all-lamps-with-minimum-number-of-moves?noredirect=1&lq=1 but the algorithm described there seems too hard for me to be implemented.

Comment: Welcome on Code Review! Code Review is supposed to be a platform where users review *working* code. Try adding a `)` at the end of `input.append(''.join(...)`. The syntax error should vanish now. If this fixes your problem reconsider if you still want your code to be reviewed, otherwise move your question so Stack Overflow until you arrive at a working solution.